# how to plot prediction on the top of the actual data plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, data-science, random-forest

When i plot only the actual values (original dataset) , It looks fine but when i try to plot my predictions onto actual data's plot, things got bad.

plotting function :

```
def plotData(df , predicted ) : 
   fig1= plt.figure(figsize= (15 ,5)); 
   plt.subplot(1 ,2  ,1); 
   df.plot(x = 'Date' , y = ['Close'] )
   plt.plot(df['Date'] , predicted)
   plt.title('BitcoinPrice - Date') 
   plt.xlabel('Date')
   plt.ylabel('Prices')
   plt.close(fig1)


   fig2 = plt.figure(figsize=(15,5)); 
   plt.subplot(1,2,2); 
   df.plot(x='Date' , y = 'Volume')
   plt.title('BitcoinVolume-Date') 
   plt.xlabel('Date')
   plt.ylabel('Volume')
   plt.legend(loc ='best')
   plt.close(fig2)
```

I send the actual dataframe and predicted values as "predicted" . For example when i create a function without "predicted" values argument , function plots these correct.

correct plots :
[correct price plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zipQF.png)

[correct volume plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ix1y2.png)

my model :

```
plotData(bitcoinDatrain , x_test, y_train , y_test = train_test_split(date , price ,  test_size =  0.25, random_state = 0)
forest_model = RandomForestRegressor(random_state = 1 )
forest_model.fit(date  , price.ravel())
forest_predictions = forest_model.predict(date)
MAEForest = mean_squared_error(forest_predictions , price)
plotData(bitcoinDataFrame  , forest_predictions )
```

and the wrong plots after calling my function :
[incorrect price plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Juee.png)
[incorrect volume plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqGRl.png)

So  , what am I doing wrong in there ?

Comment: Can you provide where you got the data?

Comment: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BTC-USD/history/ @Seankala